# Polya's theorem on polynomials, "Proofs from THE BOOK""

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I have a small question about the proof of the following statement by Pólya from "Proofs from THE BOOK, Springer 2014"

Let $$f(z) = z^n + b_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + b_0$$ be a complex polynomial, degree $n\geq 1$, leading coefficient $1$. Associate with $f(z)$ the set
$$\mathcal{C} := \{ z\in \mathbb{C}: |f(z)| \leq 2 \}$$

***Take any line $L$ in the complex plane and consider the orthogonal projection $\mathcal{C}_L$ of the set $\mathcal{C}$ onto $L$. Then the total length of any such projection never exceeds $4$.***

The proof says that we can take $L$ as the real axis of the complex plane, by rotation and translation of the plane. My professor wants that I show that the resulting (after the rotation / translation) $\mathcal{C}'$ is again of the form $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |g(z)| \leq 2\}$ for some complex polynomial $g$ with degree $n\geq 1$ and leading coefficient $1$, in this way we can wlog assume that $L=$ real axis, $\mathcal{C}_L = \mathcal{R} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x + iy \in \mathcal{C'}\text{ for some }y\in\mathbb{R} \}$, and continue the proof using another theorem:

**Theorem**: *Let $f(z)$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n\geq 1$, and leading coefficient $1$. Set $\mathcal{C}$ as above and let $\mathcal{R}$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathcal{C}$ onto the real axis. Then there are intervals $I_1,\cdots,I_t$ on the real line which together cover $\mathcal{R}$ and satisfy $l(I_1) + \cdots + l(I_t)\leq 4$*

How can I show this? Which form has it?

Comment: i think the book is on the internet for free!

Comment: Yes I have a copy of this book, but the proof gives it as granted but for my professor is not so direct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the line $L$ intersects the imaginary axis at coordinate $(0,\alpha)$ and is oriented at an angle $\theta$ with respect to the real axis.  Applying a translation and rotation to the complex plane such that $L$ coincides with the real axis results in the function $f\left( {ze^{i\theta} + \alpha i} \right)$.  So, we may take $$g\left( z \right) = e^{-in\theta } f\left( {ze^{i\theta} + \alpha i} \right )$$ to ensure that the polynomial has a leading coefficient of $1$.  This clearly satisfies $$\mathcal{C}'=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |g(z)| \leq 2\}.$$